How to make a star chart from cartesian coordinates of stars?
I used GAIA DR3 data to plot cartesian coordinates of stars around a planet. However, I am having trouble creating star chart.
At first the idea came to my mind was that I would visualize the half of the sphere of stars around the planet from a far away position. But constellation drawn from far away position wasn't the same(distorted badly) from the observation point on the planet. This is obvious since drawing constellations in a 2d plane doesn't indicate the proper 3d positions of stars. [The following image explains the problem]
 

Is the problem I'm facing is normal for star charts? If not how can I
approach on making a star chart from 3d coordinates of stars?


It's impossible to map a sphere onto a plane without some distortion. There are numerous map projections with various properties. Some are conformal: they preserve angles, which helps to preserve shapes, but areas are distorted. It's a bit easier if you're only projecting part of the celestial sphere. A couple of useful projection types (that  are fairly easy to compute) are stereographic & the closely related gnomonic

The stereographic projection is generally the most commonly used projection for star charts.
